# What are the benefits of using spectral k-means over simple k-means?

Tags: machine-learning, comparison, unsupervised-learning, k-means, spectral-clustering

[I have understood why k-means can get stuck in local minima](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4421638).

Now, I am curious to know how the spectral k-means helps to avoid this local minima problem.

According to this paper [A tutorial on Spectral](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11222-007-9033-z.pdf), The spectral algorithm goes in the following way

1. Project data into  $R^n$  matrix
2. Define an Affinity matrix A , using a Gaussian Kernel K or an
   Adjacency matrix
3. Construct the Graph Laplacian from A (i.e. decide on a
   normalization)
4. Solve the Eigenvalue problem
5. Select k eigenvectors corresponding to the k lowest (or highest)
   eigenvalues to define a k-dimensional subspace
6. Form clusters in this subspace using k-means

In step 6, it is using k-means. **How is it overcoming the local minima problem of k-means**? Moreover, what are the benefits of spectral over k-means?

If someone gives detailed insight upon this, it will be very helpful for me.